# Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Here on Health.SE, we have suffered a drought of visitors. We are averaging less than 100 visitors a day. We should be around 500 at a minimum. We are doing okay question-wise, but we need more visitors. We can fix this by getting more users. We have just over 500 as of now, but if we can get more users to join, then our other stats will begin to increase. A good way to attract more active users is Community Promotion Ads. These ads go on graduated SE sites and can help attract active users from graduated sites.

Here is part of the canonical spiel given on meta posts on graduated sites where we submit our ads for voting (six upvotes and our ad is shown on the site), repurposed for a different use:

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about the stuff your community deems important. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are relevant to your own community's interests, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

For more information, see [What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-community-ad-for-a-beta-site)

So please, go out and create ads for Health. Submit them here with the image of the ad you've made and what site it should go on.

---

We've submitted several ads already, please vote for them if you like them

- [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3041/15841) - 5 more votes
- [Gaming Stack Exchange](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/community-promotion-ads-2015/10574#10574) - 6 more votes
- [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/community-promotion-ads-2015/6930#6930) - 5 more votes
- [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6845#6845) - 4 more votes

**In action**

- [Cooking Stack Exchange](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2067/35675)
- [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2745/16382)

Comment: I'd like to use Dr. Crusher with a tricorder, but that's off limits, I'm sure. :( *thinking...*

Comment: I'm happy to do some designs, but I need the ideas - I'm rubbish for some inspiration :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/313/163 :P?

Answer (score 8):

[image]

© Tim 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

[Original image that design is based on](http://www.just-health.com.au/assets/marketing/1.jpg) (not included in design).

[Bigger image (2200 x 2500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em7p5.png)

[SVG (with non editable text, because of font)](https://openclipart.org/detail/219102).

Comment: This got in! It's had 300 clickthroughs so far!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

© Tim 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

[Original image that design is based on](http://web-dvm.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Syringe.jpg) (not included in design).

[[Bigger image (2113 x 2400)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGBwd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGBwd.png)

[SVG (with non editable text, because of font)](https://openclipart.org/detail/230251/advert-for-health-se-syringe-new-font)

Comment: If you are able to edit this, I would ask that you remove the *dot* in *health.se.* That domain name does not belong to us and I get the occasional email from site owners thanking us for sending them so many users. If you must abbreviate, the proper way to write this is **Health SE**.

Comment: @RobertCartaino will the updated version be okay?

Comment: Tim, Looks good. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again Tim, I'm going to post this right now on Chemistry SE to see what type of feedback it gets. If it gets some votes (which I think it will), then we can post it on other sites too :)

Comment: @michaelpri will you post the other one? vvv

Comment: Please change the font and make it easier on eyes.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Considering it has been posted on the other sites, it's a little late to do so. I may make an alternative version but I won't change it over as people have been voting on it. It would also change the line lengths, and wouldn't have the same proportions.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Could the changes you suggested be written about [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)? It currently doesn't mention the NAME SE vs NAME.SE guideline.

Comment: Hey Tim, I was wondering if you might be able to change the font on some of these ads. [Some people](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/community-promotion-ads-2015/3041#comment3204_3041) have been saying how it is a bit hard to read. I wouldn't mind just changing the picture if you did change them. Thanks :)

Comment: @michaelpri i will do, I'm a little busy atm... Soon tho!

Comment: Don't feel rushed, but thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

© Tim 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

[Original image that design is based on](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/404.png) (not included in design).

[Bigger image (2200 x 2500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqjYY.png)

[SVG (with non editable text, because of font)](https://openclipart.org/detail/230252).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

© Tim 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

[Original image that design is based on](http://assets.dnainfo.com/generated/photo/2013/08/cigarette-1377699012.png/larger.jpg) (not included in design).

[Bigger image (2200 x 2500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kILIJ.png)

[SVG (with non editable text, because of font)](https://openclipart.org/detail/219106/).

Comment: Nice ad.  If somebody comes here looking for the answer to that question, will he find an answer?

Comment: @MonicaCellio not sure... Hope so. I may ask but am quite busy atm to form a good question :/

Answer (score 5):

[image]

© Tim 2015. Licensed [CC by SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

[Original image that design is based on](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--IG0FVGbp--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/qebdkecladyjwi0fpqju.jpg) (not included in design).

[Bigger image (2200 x 2500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZEuu.png)

[SVG (with non editable text, because of font)](https://openclipart.org/detail/219176/).

Comment: A Tricorder!!! :D

Comment: @anongoodnurse you like?

Comment: **Very** much! :D

Comment: @anongoodnurse very difficult to make, I was making a 2D image from an angled 3D image :P

Comment: I love it! It's *fantastic*!!!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Comment: Posted in [Academia](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1773/14341)

Answer (score 2):

[image: image description]

Comment: Post in [Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6845/41634)