# Advancing Health SE

Tags: discussion

We are just over 50 days into our site's beta period, and over that period of time, we have advanced a lot. We've held a lot of [discussions about our scope](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope), shared a lot of great information, and have done some [spring cleaning](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/the-road-to-public-beta-time-to-clean-up-qa-on-health-stack-exchange). We are making a lot of progress as an SE site, but we have many things to work on.

One of our current problems is that we aren't even attracting over 100 users per day, but we have [already started to address this](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/community-promotion-ads). Right now, we have two other big problems. One is that we don't have enough answers. Over 20% of our questions are unanswered, and we don't even average one answer per question. Another is that we don't have a strong enough user base. We currently have only 2 users with 2000 rep and none with 3000. We also only have just over 50 users with 200 rep. We have to rely mostly on our moderators to close questions and delete answers, but our ultimate goal should be for the moderators to do as little as possible.

Not to despair though, we can fix our problems. One of the most important parts of a beta is for [everyone to vote](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

> It’s only through voting that a class of editors, closers, and moderators can emerge to help run and govern the site.

We need to vote more. We aren't even averaging 40 votes per day. *Each user* has 40 votes and we should all be trying to use them all. I'll admit, there are somedays where I have wasted most of my votes, but this is something that everyone needs to work on. It is a bit hard to vote when we are hardly getting 10 total posts per day (our second problem), but you can go back and vote on questions and answers posted earlier in our private beta and early days of public beta. Also, don't look at this as me saying "Go out and give reputation." Votes should be used to weed out the good posts from the bad. Give upvotes to questions that people have actually put effort into and answers that provide useful answers that improve the quality of this site and the internet overall.

Our second problem, which I mentioned earlier, is that we don't have enough questions and answers. I'm not too worried about the question amount as much as the answer amount, though. We usually have around 5 or 6  questions per day which is about average, but in the past few weeks, we've only had about 3 answers per day. It's not that we have too many questions, it's just that we have too few answers. We need dedicated users who are willing to put in the effort and do the research or share their knowledge (backed up by resources, of course) about the questions asked here. Maybe users don't want to answer bad quality questions, or maybe they don't want to waste their time answering a question that already has an answer. We should forget these excuses and answer anyway. You never know when your answer might provide knowledge that no one on this site has. I challenge you, the users of Health SE, to go out and answer questions that don't have any answers, and even questions that do have answers that you believe you can do better than.

Comment: Do you have some statistics regarding the number of questions that have been closed/deleted, as well as the number of answers that have been deleted?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt [47 questions closed, not as dupes, and not deleted](http://health.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano) (11%). [81 questions have been deleted](http://health.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+deleted%3Ayes), [51 of those had been closed previously](http://health.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+deleted%3Ayes+closed%3Ayes). In total, [64 answers have been deleted](http://health.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+deleted%3Ayes), 10 of those were self deleted. Others were deleted for moderation reasons, or because questions were deleted.

Comment: One problem with "how many answers/question" is that this site has a fair number of questions where there's clearly *an* answer.